# Is the sum of the amplitudes of an electromagnetic wave always 1?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

It's been a while, and I'm trying to verify my understanding. I remember reasoning (but never being taught) that the sum of the (normalized) electric and magnetic waves in a single electromagnetic wave at any single point in time is always one. Like so:

```
Given A of em-wave is normalized (max = 1, min = -1)

    abs(sum(A of m-wave, A of e-wave)) = 1
```

I haven't been able to find anywhere that says this specifically (I probably suck at searching, or am wrong). Am I correct in my understanding?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem from [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4071/popular-depictions-of-electromagnetic-wave-is-there-an-error?rq=1), that I am incorrect, as it has both waveforms reaching their zero simultaneously. From that question, it seems that the sums of the amplitudes ranges from -2 to 2; essentially just a doubled amplitude of a single wave (as far as sums go). Sad, as I rather enjoyed the symmetry of my interpretation. Oh well.