# Visualization of electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation

In the Wikipedia article about [electromagnetic radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation) one can find the following picture:
[image: Electromagnetic relationship]

But shouldn't the E and B field be 90$^\circ$ out of phase? In the depicted way the energy isn't conserved. At 0 the energy is 0 and at $\frac{\pi}{2}$ the energy is maximal in both fields.

Comment: I've found the answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/4071/

Comment: If you found the answer on another question, please deleted this one.

Comment: @JamalS not necessary, he will lose the points. The moderators can mark it as duplicate if you flag them

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the energy density going to zero, but is this a problem?  Remember that this is a traveling wave. The energy in the crests is being carried along ... it doesn't disappear.  Energy is conserved.  It's moving along.

Comment: Yes I just read what is written here:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4071/popular-depictions-of-electromagnetic-wave-is-there-an-error?rq=1