# Can a single photon be elliptically polarised?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons

Can a single photon be elliptically polarised ? or is elliptically polarised EM-radiation a mixture of circular and linear polarised ?

Comment: Note that in quantum optics "mixing" is sometimes used for coherent superpositions (e.g., one "mixes" beams at a beamsplitter).

Comment: I wasn't aware of that usage. I would have used "mixing" to mean incoherent only. I imagine that could be confusing when talking to people with different specialties!

Comment: @elfino It is indeed confusing. Just search the web for "mixed on a beam splitter". (I could however imagine that this nomenclature originates in classical optics.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single photon **can indeed** be elliptically polarized. A photon is, ultimately, a (quantized) excitation of a specific mode of the electromagnetic field, and while it is usually convenient to use modes with specific properties (like a definite frequency, wavevector, or linear or circular polarization), this is in general not necessary, and there are plenty of ways to define modes with elliptical polarization, or even with a spatially-dependent polarization.

On the other hand, even if you have a single photon that's elliptically polarized, in general it will also be possible to describe it as a superposition of a horizontally polarized photon and a vertically polarized one, as well as a superposition of circularly polarized photons. However, this is a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring), because the statement "the system is in a superposition state" is *always* true, unless you're working in a trivial space of dimension 1.

To give just one example of this, a wavefunction $\psi(x)=Ae^{-x^22/\sigma^2}$ with a tight width $\sigma$ might be considered to just be the state "the particle is very close to the origin", and one would be justified in thinking this is just "one state". However, a look at its momentum-space representation shows that this state is also the superposition of very many momentum states with a very wide span in momentum. So is the system in a superposition or not? It's a meaningless question!

So: you can indeed have states of the EM field which contain a single photon with a well-defined elliptical polarization. These states are also superpositions (but note that this is different from a [mixed state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states)!) of linearly polarized photons and of circularly polarized photons. And the distinction is meaningless otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it can. Using a combination of polarizers and waveplates you can produce any pure polarization you want, from linear to circular to elliptical. And you can verify this by further combinations of polarizers and waveplates, undoing the polarization change and setting up a situation where a photon would only get through 100% of the time if it were, say, elliptically polarized at some particular point in the beam path.

There's nothing fundamentally more "real" about any of these states than any others. All of these are still pure states. There's no rule that says a pure state has to be in any sense "nice" or symmetrical or anything. Remember that a pure state in one basis is a superposition in another; there's no fact of the matter as to whether it "really" is a superposition or not.

This is distinct from the situation in, say, an unpolarized beam. The polarization state of such a beam *cannot* be described with any pure state. Instead you have to use a density operator, which in effect describes a classical-ish probability distribution of quantum mechanical pure states.

Answer (score -3):

Not a photon in a definite state of polarization (helicity +1 or -1).  However, you can always entangle it with another photon and make the degree of polarization uncertain.

Comment: How is "elliptical polarization with ellipticity $\varepsilon$" not a definite state of polarization?

Comment: Because a single photon is ONLY either right-hand circularly polarized or left-hand circularly polarized.  Each corresponds to a certain helicity.

Comment: That is completely incorrect. It is perfectly possible to formulate field quantization in a mode basis with elliptical polarizations. The resulting quantum states will not have definite spin angular momentum, but that is a complete non-issue, in the same way that plane waves do not have definite orbital angular momentum and nobody calls them out on it.

Comment: I concur with Emilio Pisanty. There's nothing special about the helicity basis. You can use any basis you want. It's mathematical convenience, not an element of physical reality.

Comment: I think the issue is what is meant by "single photon", mixed states, and pure states. If we are dealing with the "simple" case of truly 1 photon in a pure state then I don't think you are correct.  However, if you allow more than "one state" wither mixed or pure then, sure I agree.  cf: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2605.pdf

Comment: That paper looks pretty fringe to me, by its own admission (it explicitly contrasts itself to the "orthodox" view in multiple places), and it's also apparently not peer-reviewed. Doesn't seem like it's in keeping with the standards for answers here.

Comment: The Kadin & Kaplan paper has been discussed here before, in [Is a single photon always circularly polarized?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/213182/) (which is also a potential duplicate I thought existed but couldn't find). The consensus was pretty roughly that the paper is suspect and should not be built upon without very careful arguments. As elifino points out it has yet to pass peer review; somewhat more concerningly it did not make the [special issue](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/tocresult.jsp?isnumber=6895192) it was submitted to, which does indicate that peer review (cont.)

Comment: unearthed issues with the paper which have yet to be corrected. Kadin and Kaplan explicitly say that they describe non-standard QM so one cannot draw conclusions about standard QM from that paper; at best it is a proposal for an experiment that would be unexplainable QM, and at worst it's a misunderstanding of current experimental realities. In any case, it is perfectly possible to prepare single photons (i.e. states that will produce Mandel dips)  which are elliptically polarized, so it's hard to see how the first statement in your last comment is correct.